# Tractor beam and Beaming off a ship

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager

In Star Trek, when a ship is caught by a tractor beam, is it possible to beam people off/on this ship?

Comment: In practice no, not unless you're dramatically more advanced than the ship using the tractor, in which case yes.

Comment: I don't recall it ever coming up (but, then, I only watched TOS, NextGen and a few DS9 and Voyager episodes), but it seems plausible, but very risky.  Memory Alpha indicates that a [Tractor beam](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Tractor_beam) is a confined Graviton Beam.  As such it shouldn't directly block a transporter beam, but it is not unreasonable to think that it might distort the heck out of it it, rendering it less than safe.  That said, I dunno how much effect gravity (specifically from a Graviton beam) has on subspace transmissions.

Comment: Usually, a tractor beam is depicted as acting on the outer surface of the ship (it's a beam that is blocked by the first thing it reaches).   So it doesn't seem like that would affect beaming to/from the interior of the ship -- you know, unless the plot demands it.

Comment: As @K-H-W says, neither did I encounter such a thing in the TV series or the movies (up to the latest Star-trek Discovery). The transporters convert the subject into energy and transfer said energy to the destination. So I think that this energy transfer wont be interfered by the tractor beam's field. But once again, an explanation might appear whence the plot demands for it :p

Comment: Depends on who the writer is for that episode doesn't it?

Comment: I believe it is the shield that prevents the transporting not the tracker beam.  I know they talk about dropping shields and activating the transporter.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

Captain Janeway did just this to a runaway miscreant in the *Voyager* episode *"[Critical Care](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Critical_Care_(episode))"*:

> Voyager finds Gar's ship – and bio-signs – and drops out of warp right on top of him, latching on a tractor beam. Gar hails them, and when they demand The Doctor, he claims to know nothing. When he tries to break their tractor beam with a feedback pulse, Janeway just beams him to the brig.

Comment: Well, in this case, Janeway is in control of both the tractor beam and the transporter, so it may not be the best example.   It's plausible that they can work in concert, or just that the tractor beam is released just before the transport.